# JavaScript+Html:Insert JavaScript Variables into a buttons' onclick function arguments

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm  new to this and I'm trying to setup a little Website just for fun and now I ran into my first major problem.

So what do I wanna do?

I got this:

```
 function CaesarCipher(str) {

 str = str.toLowerCase();

 var result = '';
 var charcode = 0;

 for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
     charcode = (str[i].charCodeAt()) + 2;
     result += String.fromCharCode(charcode);
 }
 return result;}`
```

Which I am calling with:

`<button class="babo" name="button" id="kelp" onclick="CaesarCipher()"></button>`

Also I got this:

```
<input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" id="help" required  />
            <label for="name" class="label-name">
                <span class="content-name">Your Text</span>
           </label>
The contents of the 
<input>
```

Are saved in this:

```
var x = document.getElementById("help").value;
```

Now to my plan.

I want to get the value of "x" (from the javascript file) into the parameters of the function call `onclick="CaesarCipher()"`

How do I get the text that's in the input `box= var "x"` into the button onclick call?

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you don't have to do what you are asking. You can get the value of help within the function itself.

```
function CaesarCipher() {
var str = document.getElementById("help").value;
```

Comment: This way he will lose some flexibility because this way he would hard-code the id of the element into the function definition. Extracting it to the parameter makes the function more reusable because it's not limited to one element but it will handle every string passed as an argument

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Element.addEventListener()` and get rid of `onclick=""` attribute. In your case:

```
var x = document.getElementById("help").value;
var button = document.getElementById('kelp');
button.addEventListener('click', function (e) {

    CaesarCipher(x);
});
```

Generally, it's a better idea to separate HTML template from the JS logic because you have a clean project and you know where to look for different things.

Comment: Whats wrong with onclick? addeventlistener seems kinda too much for what im doing, its kinda out of place.. but thanks for your suggestion! ill get it in mind!!

Comment: As I said, it's better to keep JS logic separate from HTML template to keep your project clean. It's not required, it's just good practice. Except that, the effect is the same as using the `onclick` attribute. If you don't like the syntax, you can equally do it with `button.onclick = function(e){ CaesarCipher(x); };` and again the effect is the same. The main advantages here are: 1. clean project structure and 2. your cipher function will be much more reusable since the input string will remain an argument instead of being hard-coded (hardcoding is really bad practice)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example from w3schools i think it will help you [1]

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_text_value_formval